# Cannot use string offset as an array in

Tags: php

I have an array $aMethods whose print_r output is this:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [pattern] => 
             [return_media] => 1
             [return_name] => 
         )

 )
```

I'm trying to access 'return_media' with this code:

```
 $iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]->return_media;
 echo $iReturnMedia;
```

Also, when I tried this:

```
 $iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]['return_media'];
```

I get an error stating: Cannot use string offset as an array in...

But it's not working, $iReturnMedia comes back as blank. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: $aMethods is set in a foreach loop as such:

```
 foreach ($aMethodList as $sMethodGroup => $aMethods) { //insert code from above }
```

Comment: You should turn on warnings; they would have told you exactly what was going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
$iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]['return_media'];
```

The operation `->` is for accessing object properties. Since you're just dealing with nested arrays, you need to index them with `[]`.

Comment: When I do that I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/user/public_html/test.php on line 89

Comment: @ElliotB., what is `line 89` ?

Comment: Line 89 is this:  $iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]['return_media'];

Comment: Why all the thumbs up? The suggested solution is not working.

Comment: People vote silly on SO. @ElliotB. Provide the code where $aMethods is set.

Comment: foreach ($aMethodList as $sMethodGroup => $aMethods) {  //insert code from above }

Comment: What happens when you put `echo $aMethods['return_media'];` in the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Access the array value by key.

```
$iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]['return_media'];
echo $iReturnMedia;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your accessing it as if it was an object in an array, you do it like:

```
$iReturnMedia = $aMethods[0]['return_media'];
 echo $iReturnMedia;
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I edited your comment instead of mine.  Feel free to ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$iReturnMedia = $aMethodList[$sMethodGroup][0]['return_media'];
echo $iReturnMedia;
```

Try to `var_dump($aMethods)` . It will be give exactly idea of that array...

Answer (score 0):

find below the code to access the array values -

```
foreach ($aMethodList as $sMethodGroup => $aMethods) { 
 echo $aMethods[0]['return_media'];
}
```